# Labels won't set to display inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 3 labels to display inline, but for some reason they don't and stays on the same line. What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>

.topBar {
display: inline;        
}   

</style>

<label class = "topBar">One</label>
<label class = "topBar">Two</label>
<label class = "topBar">Three</label>
```

Comment: They are `labels` lol That is **the** problem.

Comment: For me, they are all on the same line. Are they on different lines for you?

Comment: The labels are already in line, so everything looks good to me.

Comment: You say _"I'm trying to get 3 labels to display inline"_ ... then _"they don't \[display inline] and stays on the same line"_ —— `inine` **is** _on the same line_.  If you don't want them on the same line try making them `display: block;`

Comment: @StephenP Looks like you're the only one paying attention to the explanation. Make an answer and I'll up vote and accept. 25 points. :)

Comment: @frosty Your sentence is not correct English ("they don't and stays") so people surely thought you were more struggling with the language than with CSS properties names.  I don't even understand how it is possible to miss the fact that `display:inline` is for displaying inline, that's pretty much the only thing to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want...

> "I'm trying to get 3 labels to display inline"

but then say

> "they don't [display inline] and stays on the same line"

The display attribute `inline` ***means*** to display them on the same line.

If you want them stacked / each on its own line, try setting `display: block;`

If these are part of something, a nav block or some related items, you can reduce the tagging you do with classes by putting them together in a container that has the "topBar" class

```css
div.topBar label {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
    <label>One</label>
    <label>Two</label>
    <label>Three</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working :

```css
.topBar {
display: inline;        
}
```

```html
<label class="topBar">One</label>
<label class="topBar">Two</label>
<label class="topBar">Three</label>
```

This is even the default behavior in most browsers, see example with no css :

```html
<label class="topBar">One</label>
<label class="topBar">Two</label>
<label class="topBar">Three</label>
```

If it's not working, it's probably due to a conflicting rule. Try adding [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) :

```
label.topBar {
display: inline;        
}
```

Or

```
#mypage label.topBar {
display: inline;        
}
```